# Atalho de geração de código

Tags: android-studio

Gostaria de saber se há alguma funcionalidade no Android Studio em que eu digito uma palavra e a IDE insere um complemento (OBS: Em que eu informasse isso, e não a própria IDE). Exemplo:

```
buttonobj -> Button btnexemplo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnexemplo);
```

Ao digitar `buttonobj`+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> ela inseriria:

```
Button btnexemplo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnexemplo);
```

Existe essa funcionalidade no NetBeans, alguém saberia me dizer se há no Android Studio? E onde configuro isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O nome disso é Live Templates(fyk, no visual studio é snippets).
Pra ver/editar/adicionar seus live templates, vai em `Files` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `Live Templates` escolhe o que você quer(android, por exemplo). Pra adicionar um novo é só clicar no símbolo de mais verde do lado.
Pra inserir no código um live template é só clicar no menu em `Code` > `Insert Live Template` ou `CTRL`+`J`

Edit:
Resposta parcial no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16857108/code-snippets-in-android-studio)

Comment: Obrigado Marceloawq, era isso mesmo o que procurava.